# Actualizar UI dentro de backgroundworker en hilo sin fin con C# y WinForms

Tags: c#, windows-forms, hilos, backgroundworker

Tengo una aplicación hecha en Windows forms que se encarga de buscar infinitamente en una base de datos por tareas para realizar.

Cuando ejecuto el código dentro del Constructor de la forma, este funciona pero a momentos se detiene al lanzar nuevos hilos. La aplicación consta de muchos hilos que buscan tareas, lanzan tareas, terminan tareas y obtener actualizaciones de la base de datos para mantener una "pool" de hilos.

El problema que tengo es que al intentar mover el código del Construct a un BackgroundWoker, no puedo actualizar un campo de texto que tengo a manera de "consola de salida". Al intentar actualizar mi control `txtConsoleOut` este arroja la siguiente excepción:
`"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'txtConsoleOut' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."`

Buscando encontré como hacer para actualizar la UI utilizando el método `RunWorkerCompleted` pero no me sirve porque la aplicación nunca debe terminar el loop de búsqueda.

Existe alguna manera de actualizar el control desde un hilo que no lo comenzó?
déjo mi código de la parte que arroja la excepción

Constructor:

```
public frmAdminDespachador()
        {
            JsonConfig.rutaJson = "Despachador.json";
            InitializeComponent();
            InicializarCampos();
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

DoWork del BackgroundWorker

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //Thread.Sleep(10000);
                tConsola.Text = "";
                Log.Info("*********************************************************", APPNAME, tConsola);
                Log.Info("Iniciando aplicación", APPNAME, tConsola);
                Log.Info("*********************************************************", APPNAME, tConsola);
                //Mas código
```

Log.Info es un método de extensión de Log4Net

```
public static void Info(this ILog log, string cadena, string guid,TextBox textBox)
        {
            ThreadContext.Stacks["guid"].Clear();
            ThreadContext.Stacks["guid"].Push(guid);
            log.Info(cadena);
            textBox.AppendText(cadena + "\n");
        }
```

Gracias por adelantado

Comment: Creo que deberias separar tu solución como una respuesta a tu pregunta(problema) 
De otra manera esta pregunta no tendría sentido.

Comment: Hola @Killbunny, me alegro de que encontraras la solución, pero por favor, no edites la pregunta para poner "Solucionado" y la respuesta. En su lugar, escribe una respuesta. Ten en cuenta que Stack Overflow no es un foro donde se hacen ese tipo de cosas, sino un sitio de preguntas y respuestas (Q&A) donde la pregunta va en una sección y la respuesta va en otra. Lee [ask] y [answer] para más información. En Stack Overflow están bien vistas las preguntas auto-respondidas.

Comment: Gracias, edité la pregunta y agregué mi respuesta.

Comment: Habiendo mejores soluciones vas y usas una BackGroundWorker, que ya está obsoleto.

Comment: @Luis ¿Cuál solución me recomiendas entonces? Aún tengo oportunidad de hacer cambios en la aplicación. Aunque me parece extraño pues en docs.microsoft.com menciona que la [manera preferida es usando BackgroundWorker](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls#making-thread-safe-calls-by-using-backgroundworker)

Comment: Winforms es una tecnología ya de por si antigua, no dudo que la documentación no haya sido modificada desde hace mucho. Tienes por un lado las Reactive Extensions, manejan muy bien los procesos asíncronos, pero igual es un concepto un poco difícil si no las conoces. Lo más fácil es usar métodos asíncronos (async/await) y usar un IProgress para actualizar la interfaz.

Comment: Otra cosa, quizás te esté pasando lo que me pasó a mi,  me tocó hacer una aplicación winforms que administraba tareas, el cliente enviaba y recibía notificaciones, y había que mantener actualizada la UI, llegó un momento que era imposible mantener todo bajo control, llegaba incluso a trabarse. Al final reescribí casi todo el código e implementé MVVM usando ReactiveUI, aparte imvestiga sobre cómo recibir notificaciones de SQL Server (si es que usas ese servidor), así te llegan solitas las notificaciones y no tienes que estar haciendo consultas con hilos.

Comment: Buscaré información sobre ReactiveX. Y el tema con SQL es que todas las tablas usadas son generadas por un ERP, por lo que no estoy autorizado a jugar mucho con ellas. Igualmente gracias por el comentario! lo tendré en cuenta si esto se comienza a tornar inmanejable!

Comment: No tienes que hacer ningun cambio a tablas, es una funcionalidad de Sql Server, desde la versión 2005. Basicamente te manda notificaciones de cambios de la tabla que le indiques, inserción, modificación y eliminación de registros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré la solución:

La solución fue hacer un BeginInvoke en la extensión del Log.

```
public static void Info(this ILog log, string cadena, string guid,TextBox textBox)
    {
        ThreadContext.Stacks["guid"].Clear();
        ThreadContext.Stacks["guid"].Push(guid);
        log.Info(cadena);
        //Esta fue la modificación:
        textBox.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { textBox.AppendText(cadena + "\n"); }));
    }
```